# Number of Irreducible Factors of $x^{63} - 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-fields, computational-algebra

I have to find the number of irreducible factors of $x^{63}-1$ over $\mathbb F_2$ using the $2$-cyclotomic cosets modulo $63$.

Is there a way to see how many the cyclotomic cosets are and what is their cardinality which is faster than the direct computation?

Thank you.

Comment: The irreducible factors are the minimal polynomials of non-zero elements of $\Bbb{F}_{64}$. The degree of the minimal polynomial of an element $\alpha$ is equal to the extension degree $n=[\Bbb{F}_2[\alpha]:\Bbb{F}_2]$ and is shared by $n$ elements - the conjugates of $\alpha$. Keep careful track of those elements that belong to a proper subfield of $\Bbb{F}_{64}$, and you get the result in the answers by Matt E and Algean. It may be faster to just tally the cyclotomic cosets :-)

Answer (score 6):

Direct computation is pretty fast in this case.

The poly. $x^{63} -1 $ factors as cyclotomic polys $\Phi_d$ for $d \mid 63$, so
$d = 1, 3, 9, 7, 21, 63.$

The corresponding degrees of $\Phi_d$ are $\phi(d)$:  $1, 2, 6, 6, 12, 36$.

To compute how $\Phi_d$ factors over $\mathbb F_2$, you have to compute
the subgroup of $(\mathbb Z/d)^{\times}$ generated by $2$; its index is
the number of factors.

Since all the $d$ divide $63$, and $2^6 = 64 \equiv 1 \bmod 63$, these groups, 
and the corresponding indices,
are pretty fast to compute.

Ultimately, one finds $13$ factors (as was already recorded in ALGEAN's answer).

Answer (score 3):

Note that $x^{p^n}-x\in\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ equals to product of all irreducible factors of degree $d$ such that $d|n$. Suppose $w_p(d)$ is the number of irreducible factors of degree $d$ on $\mathbb{Z}_p$, then we have 
$$p^n=\sum_{d|n}dw_p(d)$$
now use **Mobius Inversion Formula** to obtain
$$w_p(n)=\frac1{n}\sum_{d|n}\mu(\frac{n}{d})p^d.$$
use above identity to obtain
$$w_p(1)=p$$
$$w_p(q)=\frac{p^q-p}{q}$$
$$w_p(rs)=\frac{p^{rs}-p^r-p^s+p}{rs}$$
where $q$ is a prime number and $r,s$ distinct prime numbers.

Now you need to calculate $w_2(1)+w_2(2)+w_2(3)+w_2(6)\color{#ff0000}{-{1}}$. By using above formulas you can see that the final answer is $13$.