# Find irreducible factors without factorizing

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

I have an exercise from my course notes that states:

> Find how many irreducible factors has $f(x) = x^{26}-1$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$ and their degrees. (don't factorize it)

I see immediately that the $1$ is a root of $f$. So I have $f(x)=(x-1) g(x)$ where $g$ has degree $25$ with no root in $\mathbb{F}_3$. But I don't know really how to move.

Comment: It also has -1 as its root

Comment: What exactly have the course notes covered about finite fields at that point? E.g. do you know how their extensions look like?

Comment: In any case, e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/536029/96384 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/637898/96384 contain several methods to solve this which should be easily adapted to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distinct-degree factorization theorem tells us that $X^{27}-X$ factors mod $3$ into the product of all monic irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_3[X]$ whose degree divides $3$ (since $27 = 3^3$). So $X^{26}-1$ is the product of all monic irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_3[X]$ of degree $1$ and $3$ except $X$.

Comment: So, is there a way to count the number of such polynomials? Or do I have to list them and verify if each one has a root in $F_3$?

Comment: @lukk I don't know whether there's a way to count them. Since $\mathbb{F}_3$ only has three elements it shouldn't be too hard to identify the irreducible monic polynomials of degree $3$ (as you say, these are the ones that don't have a root in $\mathbb{F}_3$).